# Regular expression for version number (vX.X.X) not working

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to check that an input string which contains a version number of the correct format.

```
vX.X.X
```

where X can be any number of numerical digits, e.g:

```
v1.32.12   or  v0.2.2   or v1232.321.23
```

I have the following regular expression:

```
v([\d.][\d.])([\d])
```

This does not work.

Where is my error?

EDIT: I also require the string to have a max length of 20 characters, is there a way to do this through regex or is it best to just use regular Python len()

Comment: you mean the whole string length?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes, the string is stored in a `version` variable e.g. `version = "v0.2.1"` and I want to check that the total length of this variable is < 20 characters.

Comment: For length check this https://regex101.com/r/tMBYzL/1

Comment: @AvinashRaj Fantastic, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `[\d.]` should match any one character either a digit or a dot.

```
v(\d+)\.(\d+)\.\d+
```

Use `\d+` to match one or more digit characters.

*Example:*

```
>>> import re
>>> s = ['v1.32.12',  'v0.2.2'  , 'v1232.321.23', 'v1.2.434312543898765']
>>> [i for i in s if re.match(r'^(?!.{20})v(\d+)\.(\d+)\.\d+$', i)]
['v1.32.12', 'v0.2.2', 'v1232.321.23']
>>>
```

`(?!.{20})` negative lookahead at the start checks for the string length before matching. If the string length is atleast 20 then it would fails immediately without do matching on that particular string.

Comment: if it works for you, accept this answer as the solution to your question

Comment: @radicarl Done, was subject to a 15 minute limit. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

@Avinash Raj.Your answer is perfect except for one correction.
It would allow only 19 characters.Slight correction

```
>>> import re
>>> s = ['v1.32.12',  'v0.2.2'  , 'v1232.321.23', 'v1.2.434312543898765']
>>> [i for i in s if re.match(r'^(?!.{21})v(\d+)\.(\d+)\.\d+$', i)]
['v1.32.12', 'v0.2.2', 'v1232.321.23']
>>>
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42390661/regular-expression-for-version-number-vx-x-x-not-working/42390685#comment71929048_42390661 comment . It should be less than 20.